# How does Ionic's default gulpfile relate to its cli tool?

Tags: gulp, ionic-framework

Currently, I am running the app emulation using the Chrome browser with `ionic serve`. I also see that there is a gulpfile.js associated with the framework. What is the relationship between ionic and and gulp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli#advanced-serve-options (see "Gulp Integrations").

You can add a `gulpStartupTasks` property in the `ionic.project` file located in your project root.

They example the above linked documentation gives is:

```
{
  "name": "SmoothRiders",
   "gulpStartupTasks": [
    "watch"
  ]
}
```

In this case, the `watch` gulp task is executed when you run `$ ionic serve`.

If you run `$ ionic setup sass`, it will add the configuration to your `ionic.project`. Once you understand that, you're good to go so long as you understand gulp.

Comment: @david - if you get a chance, if this answers your question please upvote it - alternatively, let us know more specifically what isn't being answered so we can help you and others who might have a similar question. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Gulp is a task manager and let you perform several actions to automate your build.

I personnaly perform several actions PRE-BUILD to prepare my project before starting a proper ionic build that triggers hooks & everything normal.

My pre-build actions are mainly to customize my config.xml

> Therefore, you can build a ionic project WITHOUT using any gulp
>   commands. And you can use to help you build several steps of your
>   project

Here is an exemple of someone work with gulp to help him "boost" his build process : http://www.thomasmaximini.com/2015/02/10/speeding-up-ionic-app-development-with-gulp.html
Tasks that he performs are : SASS Compil & concatenation of severals
But he also simplifies some of ionic cli commands.