# gulpfile.js automatically created if gulp is installed globally

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, gulp

I have installed gulp globally and when I tried to create a new ionic project `gulpfile.js` was automatically created with default settings like **automatic reloading browser window** and **automatically compiling `sass` file to `css`**.

- How default settings are added into `gulfile.js` for my project?
- Can anybody please let me know what happens if I don't have gulp installed globally and I create ionic project? I mean `gulpfile.js` will be created or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally as suggestion of @Adam I got my answer.

In spite of uninstalling gulp, `gulpfile.js` gets created and resides in ionic project folder structure. 
I end up finding my answers on [How does Ionic's default gulpfile relate to its cli tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30628591/how-does-ionics-default-gulpfile-relate-to-its-cli-tool)

Thank you.